# Jquery save and restore entire page status with HTML5 localstorage

Tags: jquery, html

In my project I'm using bootgrid plugin to show the list of records (list.php).
I would like to know if I can save the state of the page (search field, pagination, etc) - redirect to another page (edit.php) and when I return to list.php restore the saved status using html5 sessionStorage and localstorage.

LIST.PHP

```
<table id="grid" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-column-id="id" data-visible="false" data-converter="numeric">id</th>
        <th data-column-id="name">Name</th>
        <th data-column-id="version">Version</th>
        <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

JS

```
var grid = $("#grid").bootgrid({
    ajax: true,
    url: "grid.php",
    rowCount        : [25, 50, -1],
    columnSelection : false,
    formatters  : {
       "commands": function(column, row) {
           return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-warning command-edit\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></span></button> " +
                  "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-danger command-delete\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></button>";
      }
   },
}).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function() {

    grid.find(".command-edit").on("click", function(e) {

    //Save page status and redirect to edit.php

    }).end().find(".command-delete").on("click", function(e) {

    //do something

    });
});
```

You can do it in my scenerio? How could I do that? Is there any plugin that could do it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Storage API to save data from fields and then check if keys are set on page load.
https://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API

Check this tutorial too
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/storing-data-on-the-client-with-localstorage